# How do I count categorical values in a "+/-" table?

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics, analysis

I have a table of n rows and 26 cloumns, with the row names as gene names and columns as the associated function of each gene. If the gene has an "+" on a particular column, then it means that the this gene is associated to this function. How do I count all the genes with an "+" for a particular pathway? I tried to turn the chart into a dataframe, say df1 and then use the summarize function, but it didn't give me the output that I wanted. I saw some posts say that str_detect() works, but that seems to be for one varible/column. 
An example of what I expect to get from Rstudio is: 
Adaptive Immune Response 4
Angeiogenesis 2
Apoptosis 4
....so on and so forth.
Here's a clipping of the chart that I mentioned
(click on the link, level's not enough for direct upload of images):
[Gene List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hizpI.png)

Whatever function or package you can suggest would be welcome, still very new to data analysis with R. Thanks

In answer to comment about uploading reproducible data:

```
structure(list(Gene = c("Cyp27a1", "Tnfrsf13c", "Igf1r", "S100a10", 
"Kit", "Hcar2", "Itgax", "Mbd2", "Asph", "Ccl7", "Dlg1", "Tgm1", 
"Gstm1", "Casp1", "Tbc1d4", "Olfml3", "Ppp3ca", "Igsf10", "Rpl28", 
"Rad1", "F3", "Gpr34", "Lrrc3", "Col6a3", "Cdc7", "Stx18", "Ccl2", 
"Ptx3", "Nfkb1", "Bola2", "Npl", "Itga6", "Slc17a7", "Prkar2a", 
"Serping1"), Cell.Type = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, "Dendritic cells", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Adaptive_Immune_Response = c("-", 
"-", "-", "-", "+", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "+", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
"-", "+", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"), Angiogenesis = c("-", 
"-", "-", "-", "+", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"), Apoptosis = c("-", "-", 
"+", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "+", "-", 
"-", "+", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
"+", "-", "-", "-", "-", "+", "-"), Astrocyte_Function = c("-", 
"-", "-", "+", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "+", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "+", 
"+", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "+"), Autophagy = c("-", "-", 
"+", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "+", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"), Carbohydrate_Metabolism = c("-", 
"-", "+", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"), Cell_Cycle = c("-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "+", "-", "-", "-", "-", "+", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"), Cellular_Stress = c("-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "+", "-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
"-", "+", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"), Cytokine_Signaling = c("-", 
"+", "-", "-", "+", "-", "-", "-", "-", "+", "-", "-", "-", "+", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "+", 
"-", "+", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"), DNA_Damage = c("-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "+", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"), Epigenetic_Regulation = c("-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "+", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"), Growth_Factor_Signaling = c("-", 
"-", "+", "-", "+", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "+", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "+", "-", "-", "-", 
"-", "+", "-", "-", "+", "-", "+", "-"), Inflammatory_Signaling = c("+", 
"+", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "+", "-", "-", "+", "-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "+", 
"-", "+", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"), Innate_Immune_Response = c("-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "+", 
"-", "-", "+", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "+", 
"-", "+", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"), Insulin_Signaling = c("-", 
"-", "+", "-", "+", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"), Lipid_Metabolism = c("-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"), Matrix_Remodeling = c("-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "+", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
"-", "+", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "+", "-", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "+", "-", "-", "-"), Microglia_Function = c("-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "+", "+", "-", "+", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
"+", "-", "-", "+", "+", "-", "+", "+", "+", "+", "-", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "+", "+", "+", "-", "-", "-"), NF.kB = c("-", "+", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
"+", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"), Neurons_and_Neurotransmission = c("-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "+", "-", "-", "-", 
"+", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "+", "-", "-"), Notch = c("-", "-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"), Oligodendrocyte_Function = c("-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"), Wnt = c("-", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
"+", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"), Human_Gene = c("CYP27A1", "TNFRSF13C", 
"IGF1R", "S100A10", "KIT", "HCAR2", "ITGAX", "MBD2", "ASPH", 
"CCL7", "DLG1", "TGM1", "GSTM1", "CASP1", "TBC1D4", "OLFML3", 
"PPP3CA", "IGSF10", "RPL28", "RAD1", "F3", "GPR34", "LRRC3", 
"COL6A3", "CDC7", "STX18", "CCL2", "PTX3", "NFKB1", "BOLA2", 
"NPL", "ITGA6", "SLC17A7", "PRKAR2A", "SERPING1")), row.names = c(181L, 
705L, 314L, 602L, 382L, 285L, 353L, 433L, 24L, 98L, 189L, 680L, 
279L, 85L, 670L, 495L, 537L, 316L, 590L, 568L, 226L, 266L, 405L, 
156L, 131L, 661L, 94L, 562L, 471L, 66L, 484L, 349L, 631L, 546L, 
612L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Share a reproducible example of your data instead of an image.

Comment: @sindri_baldur What do you mean by that? I don't understand what you mean, it's originally an excel spreadsheet. Do you want me to upload the excel file?

Comment: Your question is tagged with `R `. Import the data into `R` as a data.frame and use `dput()` to share a reasonable chunk of it.

Comment: so output it as an ASCII text file and then paste onto stack overflow?

Comment: yes, just raw text.. that reproduces the data. Paste it in and make sure to format as code.

Comment: Thanks, added the code to the orginal question. Is this better?

Comment: Exactly. Good job!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option using `table()`:

```
other_vars <- c("Gene", "Cell.Type", "Human_Gene")
pm_vars <- setdiff(names(df), other_vars)

do.call(rbind, lapply(df[pm_vars], table))

                               -  +
Adaptive_Immune_Response      32  3
Angiogenesis                  34  1
Apoptosis                     30  5
Astrocyte_Function            30  5
Autophagy                     33  2
Carbohydrate_Metabolism       34  1
Cell_Cycle                    33  2
Cellular_Stress               33  2
Cytokine_Signaling            29  6
DNA_Damage                    34  1
Epigenetic_Regulation         34  1
Growth_Factor_Signaling       28  7
Inflammatory_Signaling        29  6
Innate_Immune_Response        31  4
Insulin_Signaling             33  2
Lipid_Metabolism              35 35
Matrix_Remodeling             31  4
Microglia_Function            22 13
NF.kB                         33  2
Neurons_and_Neurotransmission 32  3
Notch                         35 35
Oligodendrocyte_Function      35 35
Wnt                           34  1
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is only "+" and "-", you can do colSums(data.frame == "+")  to tally the number of entries that are "+". And likewise for those that are "-". Below I excluded columns that i guess should not contain plus or minus using -c(..)

So try something like this:

```
counts = cbind(colSums(df[,-c(1,2,26)]=="+"),colSums(df[,-c(1,2,26)]=="-"))
colnames(counts) = c("plus","minus")

                              plus minus
Adaptive_Immune_Response         3    32
Angiogenesis                     1    34
Apoptosis                        5    30
Astrocyte_Function               5    30
Autophagy                        2    33
Carbohydrate_Metabolism          1    34
Cell_Cycle                       2    33
Cellular_Stress                  2    33
Cytokine_Signaling               6    29
DNA_Damage                       1    34
Epigenetic_Regulation            1    34
Growth_Factor_Signaling          7    28
Inflammatory_Signaling           6    29
Innate_Immune_Response           4    31
Insulin_Signaling                2    33
Lipid_Metabolism                 0    35
Matrix_Remodeling                4    31
Microglia_Function              13    22
NF.kB                            2    33
Neurons_and_Neurotransmission    3    32
Notch                            0    35
Oligodendrocyte_Function         0    35
Wnt                              1    34
```